# how to show that $[G:H\cap K]<\infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $H, K\leq G$ with $[G:H],[G:K]<\infty$ how to show that $[G:H\cap K]<\infty$ and how to find an upper bound of $[G:H\cap K]?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote by $\,T/G\,$ the **set** of all left cosets of subgroup $\,T\,$ in $\,G\,$. Let us define a function

$$f:(H\cap K)/G\to H/G\times K/G\;\;,\;\;\;f(x(H\cap K)):=(xH,xK)$$

We have that:

$$\;f(x(H\cap K))=f(y(H\cap K))\Longrightarrow xH=yH\;\wedge\;xH=yK\Longrightarrow y^{-1}x\in H\cap K\ldots$$

and the above shows $\,f\,$ is $\,1-1\,$ , so...

BTW, the above also gives you an upper bound for the index of the intersection.

Comment: When you replace $\Rightarrow$ by $\Leftrightarrow$, you also show that $f$ is well-defined.

Comment: Shouldn't it be xK=yK instead of xH=yK? From the functions we get (xH,yH)=(xK,yK)